# Running MASM 6.11 on OSX

Tags: macos, assembly, masm, dosbox

I need to use MASM 6.11 for Assembly Programming in my college. I'm using OSX 10.9.1 and have installed Dosbox 0.74 via homebrew.

After completing [MASM 611](http://www.phatcode.net/downloads.php?id=175) setup on Dosbox. When I try to run MASM `MASM611\bin\MASM` I get a segfault, and dosbox crashes.

After searching through forums, I tried running MASM 5.0 instead and it seems to be working fine.

Is there anyway to get MASM 6.11 working on dosbox?

**Update**
Autoexec section of my DOSBox preferences

```
[autoexec]
# Lines in this section will be run at startup.
# You can put your MOUNT lines here.
MOUNT C ~/DOSBox 
SET PATH=C:\MASM611\BIN;%PATH% 
SET LIB=C:\MASM611\LIB;%LIB% 
SET INCLUDE=C:\MASM611\INCLUDE;%INCLUDE% 
SET HELPFILES=C:\MASM611\HELP\*.HLP 
SET TMP=C:\TEMP 
C:
```

Answer (score 0):

MASM.EXE or ML.EXE version 6.11 probably needs the dos extender to be in a directory in the "path". The Microsoft version of this is named DOSXNT.EXE. Make sure that the bin directory that you installed MASM / ML 6.11 into is added to the path environment variable.

Comment: I have added the _autoexec_ section of dosbox preferences file above. The `MASM611\BIN` has the DOSXNT.EXE so the file is in the path variable.

Comment: Try adding the command line set tnt=-nopspgrow to set the tnt environment variable. I think that masm 6.11 uses the dos extender to switch into 32 bit protected mode. BIOS calls are used to do the switch (caller supplies table values for GDT and LDT). I don't know which dosbox versions support this. Microsoft 16 bit C compiler version 8.00c also runs in 32 bit protected mode using the dos extender. I don't have issues running either of these in a dos console window on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you can't get DosBox to work, is to try running MASM on FreeDOS inside VirtualBox.